# Android Packet data shortcut

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, mobile-data, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxy Mini running Android 2.3.3 Gingerbread. In the previous version Froyo (2.2.1) when I held down power button I got in that menu a shortcut to enable packet data. In Gingerbread I couldn't make this shortcut appear.

Is there anything I can make to add this shortcut there? Because it's quite annoying to keep accessing Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> Enable packet data.

Comment: how did you install the gingerbread on your galaxy mini...The KIES software says that there is no upgrade available for my S5570.

Comment: Using a ROM found here: http://simple-blog.eu/cum-faci-upgrade-la-android-2-3-3-gingerbread-pentru-samsung-galaxi-mini/ Unfortunately it's in Romanian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to add any custom shortcuts to Power button menu. Looks like you have installed some custom ROM. If that is the case, you could also try to find the ROM which has this feature embedded. Here's the list of custom ROMs for you phone:

[XDA-Developers: all samsung galaxy mini custom roms!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1345678)

The ROMs that are based on CyanogenMod (CM) have nice feature called Notification Power Widget, it can be customized and Mobile Data switch could be added:
[image]

If you don't want to change the ROM, you still have some options:

- As mentioned in [another comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12963/8767) to your question, you could use [Power Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.abraxas.powerwidget.free), also Android Market contains [lots of widgets](https://market.android.com/search?q=data%20widget&so=1&c=apps) specially for Data switching.
- Also you can simply automate the actions you want to do with [earlier mentioned](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/16134/8767) [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) or [Llama](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama), which is free alternative to the Tasker. With this apps you could set Mobile Data to be turned on or off depending on events like your location, or, screen on/off, etc.

Comment: I am using now APNdroid. It's a cheap and simple application which cuts the packet data connection.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do this using tasker and a plugin. It's a cost option, but it will work.

Tasker allows you to create widgets to tasks, so it doesn't have to be event based.

The plugin can be found [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.suttco.locale.net&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zdXR0Y28ubG9jYWxlLm5ldCJd)

Tasker (if you're unfamiliar with it) can be found [here](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIm5ldC5kaW5nbGlzY2guYW5kcm9pZC50YXNrZXJtIl0.)

Answer (score 0):

[This widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.abraxas.powerwidget.free) might help.  It has an airplane mode switch and "2G/3G" (I'm not sure if that's switching from one to another or includes switching both off).  There should be similar apps to do what you want if that one doesn't.

Comment: Maybe it's the best thing I can do. "Unfortunately, Android does not allow other applications to change the 2G/3G preference directly." It behaves like a shortcut to "Enable packet data".

Comment: @Daniel Ah, too bad. A one-click process would be better.